# ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c++, xcode, linker

I have no idea what this is and have been looking for a while now. New to C++ here. Any ideas, greatly appreciated! I am not even sure if I need to add more info for you guys to help, but let me know and I will provide.

Thanks!!

Not sure what kind of format to use for this text but here is the error output:

```
Ld /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Products/Debug/Map normal x86_64
    cd /Users/tobydammit/Documents/Map
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.9
    /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode6-Beta7.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -L/Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -stdlib=libc++ -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Products/Debug/Map

duplicate symbol __ZN4Map1C2Ev in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map1C1Ev in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map18setWidthEi in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map19setHeightEi in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map111setEntranceENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map17setExitENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZN4Map17setPathENSt3__112basic_stringIcNS0_11char_traitsIcEENS0_9allocatorIcEEEE in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Map18getWidthEv in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Map19getHeightEv in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Map111getEntranceEv in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Map17getExitEv in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
duplicate symbol __ZNK4Map17getPathEv in:
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Map1.o
    /Users/tobydammit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Map-avxsuohepeftazcaavamzzjpovrz/Build/Intermediates/Map.build/Debug/Map.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
ld: 12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

@WhozCraig: Here is the .h file as is.

Also, sorry for posting the screenshot!

```
#ifndef Map_Map1_h
#define Map_Map1_h


#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

class Map1 {

public:
    Map1();
    void setWidth(int);
    void setHeight(int);
    void setEntrance(string);
    void setExit(string);
    void setPath(string);
    void drawMap();
    int getWidth()const;
    int getHeight() const;
    string getEntrance() const;
    string getExit() const;
    string getPath() const;

private:
    int width;
    int height;
    string entry;
    string exit;
    string path;




};

#endif
```

Comment: I would *guess*  you included the implementation of your `Map` class in the header file without inlining (and it isn't a template). Please update your question with the `Map` header file in its *entirety*, untouched, as a code list.

Comment: And please post error messages ass text, not a screenshot.  I can't read what you've pasted.